# how to programmatically add view to scrollview in alloy

Tags: ios, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator-titanium

I'm struggling to implement adding dynamic content to the scrollview in the controller. In my xml, I've a horizontal scrollview. I need to add multiple views to the scrollview programmatically from the controller. How can I do it programmatically in Appcelerator Alloy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways possible, depending on the complexity of the view you want to add.

1)

Create a controller for the view, then add it

```
$.scrollViewId.add(Alloy.createController('subViewController').getView());
```

2)
If it is a simple view, just do

```
$.scrollViewId.add(Ti.UI.createView());
```

Since this is a pretty basic thing to do in Titanium/Alloy, you might want to dive into the documentation about Alloy https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Concepts

There are some extra chapters about Alloy in the menu on the left